# Angular filtering form

Tags: angular

I try to implement a form  filtering by date range using Angular. After button pressing nothing happened . Looks like a the route is not selected. When i just changed

[routerLink]="['/clients-rating/filtered',startDate,endDate"  to

[routerLink]="['/clients-rating/filtered','2019-03-01',2019-03-10"  i see url : http://localhost:9000/#/clients-rating/filtered/2019-03-01/2019-03-10.

Why the entered value is not transferred from the form to the component?

*My code:*

**clients-rating.component.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="start_date" 
                [(ngModel)]="startDate"/>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="end_date" 
                [(ngModel)]="endDate"/>
           <button 
                [routerLink]="['/clients-rating/filtered',startDate,endDate" 
                class="btn btn-primary float-left 
                jh-create-entity create-clients-rating">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'eye'"></fa-icon>
           </button>
       </div>
     <body>
<html>
```

**clients-rating.route.ts**

```
{
    path: 'clients-rating/filtered/:startDate/:endDate',
    component: ClientsRatingComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
```

...

**clients-rating.component.ts**

```
export class ClientsRatingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    clientsRatings: IClientsRating[];
    startDate: String;
    endDate: String;

    constructor(
        protected clientsRatingService: ClientsRatingService,
        protected jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        protected eventManager: JhiEventManager,
        protected accountService: AccountService,
        protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.clientsRatingService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IClientsRating[]>) => {
                this.clientsRatings = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.startDate =  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('startDate');
        this.endDate = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('endDate');
        if (this.startDate == null || this.endDate == null) {
            this.loadAll();
        } else {
            this.clientsRatingService.filterByDate(this.startDate,  this.endDate);
        }
            this.accountService.identity().then(account => {
                this.currentAccount = account;
            });
        this.registerChangeInClientsRatings();
    }
```

**client-rating.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ClientsRatingService {

 filterByDate(startDate: String, endDate: String,req?: any) {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http.get<IClientsRating[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/filter /${startDate}/${endDate}`, {
            params: options,
            observe: 'response'
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed `]` for routerLink

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: I missed ']' when copied/pasted here. In my code i have

Comment: you can try posted answer Also provide the code from app.module.ts

Comment: I missed "]" when i copied/pasted here , but in my code  I have ']'.  i'm expecting to get a request to url http://localhost:9000/#/clients-rating/filtered/2019-03-01/2019-03-10 where '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-10'  are value which was  entered  into  input form elemens.

Comment: Expected: `localhost:9000/#/clients-rating/filtered/2019-03-01/2019-03-10` and Current: `?????`

Comment: No , 2019-03-01 as startDate and 2019-03-10 as endDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed closing `]` for RouterLink.

But I would use [`Router.navigate`](https://angular.io/guide/router) with (click) event of the button:

TS Code:

First, import Router:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router : Router) {} 

navigateTo(){
  this.router.navigate(['clients-rating/filtered/' + startDate + '/'+endDate+'']);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="start_date" 
                [(ngModel)]="startDate"/>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="end_date" 
                [(ngModel)]="endDate"/>
           <button (click)="navigateTo()" class="btn btn-primary float-left jh-create-entity create-clients-rating">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'eye'"></fa-icon>
           </button>
       </div>
     <body>
<html>
```

Comment: this.router.navigate(['clients-rating/filtered/' + this.startDate  + '/'  +  this.endDate ])    doesn't work , 
but  
this.router.navigate(['clients-rating/filtered/' + this.startDate  +  this.endDate ])  works .